# Python: Connecting to ms sql server from linux

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, t-sql, freetds

I'm trying to connect to ms sql server hosted on a windows pc from a linux box. I'm trying to follow these instructions: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/serverthere.htm

Now, I verified that I can ping and telnet into the PC running the server. And I reached the place where the instructions are to run this:

**Example 8-3. Connecting to the server, bypassing freetds.conf**

```
$ cd src/apps
$ TDSVER=7.0 ./tsql -H myhost -p 1433 -U user
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out where src/apps is.

and when I try to run

```
$ ./tsql -S myserver -U user
```

or
`$ tsql -S server-ip -U myusername -P mypassword`

I get tsql command not found. What is happening?

Comment: Did you even install freetds? Because apparently the tsql executable cannot be located based on your PATH environment or at the current directory. For example, for Ubuntu you need to run `sudo apt-get install freetds-bin`.

Comment: That's it. I had installed freetds-dev and not freetds-bin. 
Don't I feel like an idiot now :\